# Reload only the bootstrap tab when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following `tab panel`:

```
<div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#map" data-toggle="tab" id="myTab">Map-location</a></li>
          <li><a href="#comments" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
          <% if shopper_signed_in? %>
          <li><a href="#addComments" data-toggle="tab">Add Comment</a></li>
           <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

and I would like to reload the first tab (when I click on it) in order for the map to appear.

This is what I get form the browser inspector:

```
 <a href="#map" data-toggle="tab" id="myTab">Map-location</a>
```

Currently I'm trying this:

```
<script> jQuery("#myTab").click(function() {  location.reload(true); });</script>
```

but it's not exactly what I'm after. The current setup is reloading the whole page, I would prefer if only the tab reloads when I click on it.

Comment: well what loads the tab? There is no magical method to reload just part of the page. You can use jQuery with load or ajax to fetch a part of it....

Comment: @epascarello... its a bootstrap tab panel created with `ruby rails 5`

Comment: Updated my Answer, hope it helps

Comment: If the tab panel is not dynamic and filled in on page load, than you need to load it dynamically with load or Ajax and put the content into the panel....

Answer (score 0):

What is the Server-side part behind this? Usually, the practice is to provide a server side action to provide the comments section only.

Assuming this is maybe PHP, provide `comments.php` which will return comments only, and reload the Comments tab like this:

```
$("#commentsDiv").load("comments.php?id=" + id)
```

**UPDATE** As it turns out that *Ruby* is in use, which I don't know, please adapt the solution to Ruby yourself. You just need a separate action/route for delivering comments only.

What you can also do, but it's not recommend, is to get the full content, but grab the specific part of the page only:

```
$("#commentsDiv").load(window.location.href + " #commentsDiv");
```

should be like this. This actually *is* the "magical method to reload just part of the page" :) See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/), Section **Loading Page Fragments** (as you can read there, this method has some drawbacks, so it's not really recommended, e.g. JavaScript is not executed)